# Add string into nginx.conf with command

Tags: text-processing, scripting, nginx

I need to add this string `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf` inside of `nginx.conf` file. It should look like this:

```
. . .
. . .

http {

    . . .
    . . .

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    # INCLUDE STRING HERE VIA COMMAND

}
```

I want to script something but I stucked on this step and don't know which command can do this for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append after a specific **pattern** with `sed`.

Using the syntax `/pattern/ a <string>`:

```
sed '/include.*conf/ a "New string"'
```

Like so:

```
echo "http {

    . . .
    . . .

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}" | sed '/include.*conf/ a "New string"'
http {

    . . .
    . . .

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
"New string"

}
```

If you want to append at a specific **position**, use (for example):

```
echo "http {

    . . .
    . . .


}" | sed '4 a\
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf'
http {

    . . .
    . . .
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf


}
```

...to append after the fourth line.

---

`sed` version:

```
sed (GNU sed) 4.4
```

Comment: How to persist this into a `nginx.conf` file. I want to have stock nginx.conf file with just this one line `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf` added after installing nginx.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.